# Posting ReactJs FormData with nested model files to .net core 2.2 web api

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm facing this problem. I have this nested model inside my file js

```
                                    var request={
                                        idCliente:form.idCliente,
                                        appUserId:user.data.id,
                                        idFiliale:user.data.idFiliale,
                                        idSuggeritore:form.idSuggeritore,
                                        contrattoLuceRequest:{
                                            numeroContratto:form.contratti[0].numeroContratto,
                                            idTipoContratto:form.contratti[0].idTipoContratto,
                                            idTipoOperazione:form.contratti[0].idTipoOperazione,
                                            idStatoContratto:form.contratti[0].idStatoContratto,
                                            note:form.contratti[0].note,
                                            numeroPod:form.contratti[0].contrattoLuce.numeroPod,
                                            allegati:form.contratti[0].allegatiContratto
                                        },
                                        formFiles:form.contratti[0].allegatiContratto
                                    }
```

properties "allegati" of the object "contrattoLuceRequest" and "formFiles" of the object "request", are a collection of files uploaded with the component Material Ui Dropzone.
I have to send this model to my .net core 2.2 web api backend.
This is the service that I use to build my formData object. For this test, I'm ignoring other properties...I focus my test only on "formFiles" and "allegati" properties.

```
let f = new FormData();
            for (var key2 in interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati) {
                f.append("formFiles", interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati[key2]);
            }
            for (var key3 in interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati) {
                f.append("interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati", 
                interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati[key3]);
            }
```

I send all to the server with axios

```
axios.post('/Interazioni',f,{
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }).then(response => {
                    resolve(response);
                }).catch(err=>{
                    return reject(err);
                })
```

And this is the .net core 2.2 web api

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddInterazione([FromForm] InterazioneRequest interazioneRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                if (interazioneRequest == null)
                    return BadRequest();
                await this.interazioniService.AddInterazione(interazioneRequest);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(409, ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is the server model "InterazioneRequest"

```
public class InterazioneRequest
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
        public int IdFiliale { get; set; }
        public int? IdSuggeritore { get; set; }
        public ContrattoLuceRequest ContrattoLuceRequest { get; set; }
        public ContrattoGasRequest ContrattoGasRequest { get; set; }
        public ContrattoDualRequest ContrattoDualRequest { get; set; }
        public ContrattoMultiEleRequest ContrattoMultiEleRequest { get; set; }
        public ContrattoMultiGasRequest ContrattoMultiGasRequest { get; set; }
        public IFormFileCollection formFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the "ContrattoLuceRequest" model, that is used for our test case

```
public class ContrattoLuceRequest
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string NumeroContratto { get; set; }
        public string NumeroPod { get; set; }
        public int IdStatoContratto { get; set; }
        public int IdTipoContratto { get; set; }
        public int IdTipoOperazione { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public IFormFileCollection Allegati { get; set; }       
    }
```

And now, the problem. From the frontend I post all my data to the server, but only "formFiles" are bounded correctly... the nested property "Allegati" of the object "ContrattoLuceRequest" is always null. Is it a bug, or I'm ignoring something important? I also attach here the screenshot of the request sent to the server taken on the Chrome Dev Tools. Thank you so much
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. The problem is that this part of code is not correct

```
    for (var key3 in interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati) {
        f.append("interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati", 
        interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati[key3]);
    }
```

The correct way is to remove "interazione" level, because my model on the main level is "contrattoLuceRequest", so the correct code is

```
for (var key3 in interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati) {
    f.append("contrattoLuceRequest.allegati", 
    interazione.contrattoLuceRequest.allegati[key3]);
}
```

Now is working. Sorry